# Deployment on Heroku successful bot is not working - JDA

Tags: gradle, heroku, discord, discord-jda

I have deployed my Discord Bot (gradle; JDA), and it says that the build and deployment are successful, yet the bot itself isn't working (not online). What can be the problem? My Log says that no errors were created.

Answer (score 0):

The trick I use is compiling the app myself, putting it on the folder then specifying that in the procfile.

Compile the bot into MyBot.jar and put a file called "Procfile" (no extension) in the root folder:

```
worker: java -jar MyBot.jar
```

This is definitely not the best solution, since your app is built by Heroku. Instead of creating it manually, you should configure maven/gradle to compile it it properly and replace "MyBot.jar" in the command with that.

If you guarantee it was properly deployed and it's still not working, that means there is some faulty code. Read the logs to see what's missing.